# Java Scripting

Tags: java

Есть ли какие-нибудь описания и примеры помимо [Java Scripting Programmer's Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/programmer_guide/index.html)?

**Не путать java script**

Comment: Забанили наверное :)

Comment: Насколько я помню вроде в Хорстмане было какое-то описание во втором томе (могу ошибаться)

Comment: проблема в том что при поиске в гугле все ссылается на JS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.google.ru/search?q=java+scripting+api&aq=1&oq=java+scripti&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

http://www.google.ru/search?q=java+scripting+api&aq=1&oq=java+scripti&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8